# How to enable container insights on already created ECS Fargate using AWS Console / GUI

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

How to enable container insights on already created ECS Fargate? I am running multiple ECS clusters for which container insight was not enabled while creating those. Now I have enabled that option in Account Settings. But it is for only the new cluster which I will create after enabling it. But how do I enable it on my existing cluster. Note I am running ECS Fargate and not ec2 instances.

Any help or documents is appreciated.

Note: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/deploy-container-insights-ECS-cluster.html

```
aws ecs update-cluster-settings --cluster myCICluster --settings name=containerInsights,value=enabled
```

But didn't saw any optin using GUI / AWS console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how it can be done at present AWS doesn't provide GUI controls for this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/deploy-container-insights-ECS-cluster.html

Answer (score 3):

AWS documentation does not mention any way to do via the GUI, but AWS has launched a browser based Command line for executing AWS Commands.**Cloudshell**.

Just search for the service and Paste the command there. It should work.

That should be the way to do it until AWS adds the configuration option to ECS Update UI.

Answer (score 1):

I unclicked in aws console (in account settings) then i aws cli runned the command " aws ecs update-cluster-settings --cluster myCluster --region us-east-1  --settings name=containerInsights,value=enabled ". In couple sec started to get logs in container insights.

Thank you for helping each other